# How can I filter fields before they reach Input::get("my_field")?

Tags: laravel-4

I want for example to remove the word "fck" of all input fields. I know I can do it after but it would be great if I can do it before so it applies to my entire app.

In other words, where do I have to modify the Input (or http or request) class of Laravel 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are a few possibilities. The easiest and simplest one is to simply make a new `Input` facade and override its `get` method. Something like this:

**app/extensions/FilterableInput.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input as IlluminateInput;

class FilterableInput extends IlluminateInput {

    public static function get($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        return static::filterInput(parent::get($key, $default));
    }

    // Filtering method
    protected static function filterInput($value)
    {
        if (is_string($value))
        {
            return str_replace('fck', '***', $value);
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace the `Input` alias on **app/config/app.php** with `FilterableInput` and to add `app/extensions` to your **composer.json** `autoload.classmap` settings.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, this is shitty. It will only work for `Input::get()` and fail for `Input::all()` or `Input::only()`, You'd have to extend `Illuninate\Http\Request` then, do something similar to what I did with `Input::get()`, but for its `input()` method, and then create a `ServiceProvider` to use your own extended version on the app, instead of the original one.